# Update Gradle Classpath project doesn't exist

Tags: eclipse, gradle, eclipse-plugin, buildship

A project was recently deleted from my repository and now eclipse occasionally displays the following error.

> 'Update Gradle Classpath for main_project' has encountered a problem. Project location doesn't exist: path/to/deleted/project'

I've done a cleans, gradle->refresh gradle project, deleting and re-importing the source code to eclipse, searching for all references to the deleted project, etc.

The error doesn't seem to have any negative impact on my workflow or building and running the project, however it is annoying and I'd like to figure out what's causing it and fix it.

Thanks!